# How to efficiently log metrics from API Gateway when using cache?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

My scenario is this:

- API Gateway which has a single endpoint serves roughly 250 million requests per month, backed by a Lambda function.
- Caching is enabled, and 99% of the requests hits the cache.
- The request contains query parameters which we want to derive statistics from.
- Since cache is used, most requests never hit the Lambda function. We have currently enabled full request/response logging in API Gateway to capture the query parameters in CloudWatch. Once a week, we run a script to parse the logs and compile the statistics we are interested in.

Challenges with this setup:

- Our script takes ~5 hours to run, and only gives a snapshot for the last week. We would ideally be interested in tracking the statistics continuously over time, say every 5 minutes or every hour.
- Using full request/response logging produces HUGE amounts of logs, most of which does not contain anything that we are interested in.

Ideally we would like to turn of full request/response logging but still get the statistics we are interested in. I have considered logging to CloudWatch from Lambda@Edge to be able to capture the query parameters before the request hits the cache, and then use a metric filter, or perhaps Kinesis to get the statistics we want.

Would this be a viable solution, are can you propose another setup that could solve our problems in a more efficient way without costing too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure access logging on your API ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html ) which give way to select (portion of request and response) and publish more structured logs to cloudwatch.

You can then use cloudwatch filter pattern (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html ) to generate some metrics or feed logs to your analytical engine ( or run script as you are running now ).

Comment: Thanks, I've completely missed this. Exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: After looking into this some more, I cannot find a way to log the actual request or response body. It seems that trying to use e.g. $input.params() does not work?